# Unable to install Puppet Server

Tags: puppetmaster

I am encountering an error when installing Puppet Server on CentOS6.5. I pulled down the repository for my yum install:

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-5.noarch.rpm
```

After I ran that, I proceeded to install the tool:

```
yum install puppet-server
```

after which I received the following message:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * extras: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirror.raystedman.net
Setting up Install Process
No package puppet-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I then cleared my caches located at /etc/yum.repos.d and /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-5.noarch.rpm
```

and received the following:

```
Retrieving http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-5.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DLNJo7: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 4bd6ec30: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package puppetlabs-release-5-10.noarch is already installed
```

At this point I can only assume that I am not hitting the puppet repository. I also cleared the files at /var/tmp thinking that the rpm cli was querying /var/tmp to see if the repository had been downloading.

Comment: The fact that yum installer says "No package puppet-server" available isn't very helpful. Thus leading me to conclude that I had problems with rpm tool. So please remove your downvote.

Comment: What this implies is that "No package **puppet-server** available *(for your targeted system.)*" It's there, but `yum` knows it won't work on your EL6 host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-5.noarch.rpm` the `el-5` is intended to be used by RHEL 5 based operating systems.
You are using CentOS 6, so you should use the `el-6` version instead.

Answer (score 2):

You installed the wrong repository. You need EL6, not EL5.

Remove the wrong one with

```
sudo yum remove puppetlabs-release
```

Add the right one

For 64 bit:

```
sudo rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64/puppetlabs-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

For 32-bit:

```
sudo rpm -ivh https://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/i386/puppetlabs-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

This is [well-documented](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#for-red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-derivatives).